# How do I convert gl_FragCoord to a world space point in a fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

My understanding is that you can convert gl_FragCoord to a point in world coordinates in the fragment shader if you have the inverse of the view projection matrix, the screen width, and the screen height. First, you convert `gl_FragCoord.x` and `gl_FragCoord.y` from screen space to normalized device coordinates by dividing by the width and height respectively, then scaling and offsetting them into the range [-1, 1]. Next you transform by the inverse view projection matrix to get a world space point that you can use only if you divide by the w component.

Below is the fragment shader code I have that isn't working. Note `inverse_proj` is actually set to the inverse view projection matrix:

```
#version 450

uniform mat4 inverse_proj;
uniform float screen_width;
uniform float screen_height;

out vec4 fragment;

void main()
{
    // Convert screen coordinates to normalized device coordinates (NDC)
    vec4 ndc = vec4(
        (gl_FragCoord.x / screen_width - 0.5) * 2,
        (gl_FragCoord.y / screen_height - 0.5) * 2,
        0,
        1);

    // Convert NDC throuch inverse clip coordinates to view coordinates
    vec4 clip = inverse_proj * ndc;
    vec3 view = (1 / ndc.w * clip).xyz;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: It would be ways easier (and more efficient) to pass the world position trough a varying from the vertex shader.

Answer (score 6):

> First, you convert gl_FragCoord.x and gl_FragCoord.y from screen space to normalized device coordinates

While simultaneously ignoring the fact that NDC space is *three-dimensional* (as is window space). You also forgot that the transformation from clip-space to NDC space involved a division, which you did not undo. Well, you did kinda try to undo it, but after transforming by the inverse clip transformation.

Undoing the [vertex post-processing transformations](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing) use all four components of `gl_FragCoord` (though you could make due with just 3). The first step is undoing the viewport transform, which requires getting access to the parameters given to `glDepthRange`.

That gives you the NDC coordinate. Then you have to undo the perspective divide. `gl_FragCoord.w` is given the value 1/clipW. And clipW was the divisor in that operation. So you divide by `gl_FragCoord.w` to get back into clip space.

From there, you can multiply by the inverse of the projection matrix. Though if you want world-space, the projection matrix you invert must be a world-to-projection, rather than just pure projection (which is normally camera-to-projection).

In-code:

```
vec4 ndcPos;
ndcPos.xy = ((2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy) - (2.0 * viewport.xy)) / (viewport.zw) - 1;
ndcPos.z = (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.z - gl_DepthRange.near - gl_DepthRange.far) /
    (gl_DepthRange.far - gl_DepthRange.near);
ndcPos.w = 1.0;

vec4 clipPos = ndcPos / gl_FragCoord.w;
vec4 eyePos = invPersMatrix * clipPos;
```

Where `viewport` is a uniform containing the four parameters specified by [the `glViewport` function](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Viewport_Transform), in the same order as given to that function.

Comment: Hi Nicol, could you please explain what is `viewport` variable and how is it defined?

Comment: @travnik: Done.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problems with my code. First, as Nicol pointed out, `glFragCoord.z` (depth) needs to be shifted from screen coordinates. Also, there is a mistake with the original code where I wrote `1 / ndc.w * clip` instead of `clip / clip.w`.

As noted by BDL, however, it would be more efficient to pass the world position as a varying to the fragment shader. However, the code below is a short way to achieve the desired result entirely through the fragment shader (e.g. for screen-space programs that don't have a world position per fragment and you want the view vector per fragment).

```
#version 450

uniform mat4 inverse_view_proj;
uniform float screen_width;
uniform float screen_height;

out vec4 fragment;

void main()
{
    // Convert screen coordinates to normalized device coordinates (NDC)
    vec4 ndc = vec4(
        (gl_FragCoord.x / screen_width - 0.5) * 2.0,
        (gl_FragCoord.y / screen_height - 0.5) * 2.0,
        (gl_FragCoord.z - 0.5) * 2.0,
        1.0);

    // Convert NDC throuch inverse clip coordinates to view coordinates
    vec4 clip = inverse_view_proj * ndc;
    vec3 vertex = (clip / clip.w).xyz;

    // ...
}
```